# Running Arango Shell on DC/OS cluster

Tags: arangodb, dcos

I have just set up a DC/OS cluster via Microsoft Azure, and installed Arango 3.0 on the cluster using the DC/OS dashboard (via the ssh tunnel). I am able to SSH into the cluster and communicate with the Arango cluster:

```
$ curl --dump - http://localhost:8529/_api/gharial
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: ArangoDB
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 38

{"error":false,"graphs":[],"code":200}
```

**Question #1**: Even after I insert a graph using the POST requested described [here in the docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/HTTP/Gharial/Management.html#create-a-graph), the Arango Dashboard (accessed through the DC/OS Dashboard via the ssh tunnel) doesn't show the graph. Why is that? Here is "evidence" that the graph `social` was created:

```
$ curl -X POST --data-binary @- --dump - http://localhost:8529/_api/gharial/social/vertex/male <<EOF
> {
>     "name" : "social",
>     "edgeDefinitions" : [
>       {
>         "collection" : "relation",
>         "from" : [
>           "female",
>           "male"
>         ],
>         "to" : [
>           "female",
>           "male"
>         ]
>       }
>     ]
> }
> EOF
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Etag: 129726
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: ArangoDB
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 89

$ curl --dump - http://localhost:8529/_api/gharial
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: ArangoDB
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 226

{"error":false,"graphs":[{"_key":"social","_id":"_graphs/social","_rev":"125906","edgeDefinitions":[{"collection":"relation","from":["female","male"],"to":["female","male"]}],"orphanCollections":["otherVertices"]}],"code":200}
```

---

I'm also having trouble using the Arango shell. Even though Arango is clearly installed on he server (as shown by the above curl), the Arango shell still isn't recognized:

```
$ arangosh
arangosh: command not found
```

**Question #2**: Do I have to manually install Arango onto this machine even though I already installed Arango it through the DC/OS dashboard? If so, how should I get Arango? (I tried using `apt-get` but there were differing-version issue). Or is there another way of communicated with this cluster that I'm missing?

(Basically, I'm trying to bulk-import a large graph into Arango. I feel like there should be a way of importing directly from a file -- i.e. not over HTTP -- since that is probably faster / more efficient).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you established the ssh tunnel exactly (i.e. what is localhost here?). It could be that you connected to a DBServer by mistake (it might still respond to the _api but this is then only a local operation and not known cluster wide). You have to connect to a coordinator.

Comment: I followed the instructions [here](https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/installing/cloud/azure/#step-2-accessing-dc-os) exactly. The ssh command is `ssh azureuser@masterfqdn -p 2200 -L 8000:localhost:80`, where `masterfqdn` is the URL as outputted by my deployment.

Comment: Ah, I now see that I _wasn't_ connecting to the coordinator. For future reference, I can communicate with the coordinator while ssh'ed in to masterfqdn, the IP is listed in the ArangoDB dashboard under Nodes -> Coordinator. I believe that one could also communicate with that coordinator directly if they are using something like sshuttle, but I am on a Windows machine so I have to go through masterfqdn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## #1 Graph

If I get that correctly, you only created the graph definition; there is no data inside your graph yet. So it will show up in the list of graphs, but the screen will be blank.

If you want to create a graph with content, you may [either do this using arangosh](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Graphs/index.html#example-graphs) once you've got it running, or click on '+ Add Graph', Choose the 'Example Graphs' tab, Choose one, press 'Create'. Please note that some of these graphs may collide with the empty graph you've already created, so you may want to drop it first.

## #2 - Arangosh

The DC/OS Agent deploys ArangoDB inside of docker containers. These docker containers will also contain arangosh (and [arangoimp](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Administration/Arangoimp.html)).
If I get that correctly, you're ssh-ing into the agent host? 
As you tried, you [could install the arangodb3-client package](https://www.arangodb.com/download/debian/) in the host - you need to add the repository URL first.

This is probably the most convenient way to get arangosh; Another possibility may be to attach the arango docker container and run it in there. You need to make shure you correctly connect the coordinator host; which is why installing arangosh in the agent host is more compfortable.

Comment: Thanks! #2 is totally answered. Regarding #1, I have definitely created some empty graphs and non-empty collections in arangosh, but nothing shows up in the dashboard under collections or graphs. Any insight as to why that might be?