# Arangodump between two different AWS ec2 clusters

Tags: amazon-ec2, arangodb

I have created a Graph database in ArangoDB in a 5 machine AWS cluster. I do not have enough space in the Database AWS cluster to store the dump. So I would like to take a dump of the database in an AWS instance in a different cluster. I have the key files to connect to the machines.  How to do it using Arangodump ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do get that correctly that you're using DC/OS clusters on AWS?

The problem with arangoimp is, that it doesn't know howto authenticate with the DC/OS proxy, and thus can't reach the routes it would require to import to arangodb.

The [problem is similar to Running Arango Shell on DC/OS cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363315/running-arango-shell-on-dc-os-cluster) - you want to use [sshutle as lalitlogical describes](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1947#issuecomment-236140738) to forward the ArangoDB server port (usually 8529) to your target environment.